# Dashed line in equation

Tags: equations

What I want:

[image]

What I have:

[image]

with this code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, titlepage]{report}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:quark1}
   \left( \begin{array}{c}
u \\ 
c  \\
t \end{array} \right),  \left( \begin{array}{c}
d \\
s  \\
b \end{array} \right) \hphantom{iiiii} \begin{array}{c}
\textnormal{1\textsuperscript{st}} \\
\textnormal{2\textsuperscript{nd}}  \\
\textnormal{3\textsuperscript{rd}} \end{array} 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I am trying to use `\hdashline[2pt/2pt]` which I saw in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183258/how-to-add-dash-lines-in-matrix), but it doesn't work (undefined control sequence...)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that generates that figure. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: the answer in the cited question uses the package `arydshln`.  have you used that?

Comment: I included the code, and yes @barbarabeeton I did include that. I haven't included it here because maybe might know of an alternative way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I `\stackon` your system of `array`s a `\Centerstack` of three dashed lines (with a `-3pt` shift).

```
\documentclass[11pt, titlepage]{report}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
% DASHED LINE OF SPECIFIED LENGTH
% From morsburg at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12537/
% how-can-i-make-a-horizontal-dashed-line/12553#12553
\def\dashfill{\cleaders\hbox to .5em{\rule{.4ex}{.4pt}}\hfill}
\newcommand\dashline[1]{\hbox to #1{\dashfill\hfil}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:quark1}
\renewcommand\stacktype{L}
\stackon[-3pt]{%
   \left( \begin{array}{c}
u \\ 
c  \\
t \end{array} \right),  \left( \begin{array}{c}
d \\
s  \\
b \end{array} \right) \hphantom{iiiii} \begin{array}{c}
\textnormal{1\textsuperscript{st}} \\
\textnormal{2\textsuperscript{nd}}  \\
\textnormal{3\textsuperscript{rd}} \end{array}
}{
\Centerstack{\dashline{1.7in} \dashline{1.7in} \dashline{1.7in}}
}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @SuperCiocia http://ctan.org/pkg/stackengine