# Partitioning a Matrix with lines

Tags: matrices

I was wondering how to partition a matrix with lines as shown in the picture. IF this a repeat of another question, THEN please do give me the link and I will delete mine. [image]

Thank you!

Comment: Does [that answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/183260/59109) solve your problem?

Comment: Maybe. Would I just add a 3x1 array on the right?

Comment: Yes that did thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you do it in your case.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}

\[\left(
\begin{array}{c;{2pt/1pt}c}
             & a_1    \\
d(f_0)_{x_0} & \vdots \\
             & a_1    \\ \hdashline[2pt/1pt]
0 \dots 0    & 1
\end{array}
\right)\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That way better. I did a nested array lol

Answer (score 1):

With `{pNiceArray}` of `nicematrix` (≥ 6.10a of 2022-06-26).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\NiceMatrixOptions
  {
    custom-line = 
     {
       letter = : ,            % <- for the vertical rules
       command = hdashedline , % <- for the horizontal rules
       tikz = dashed ,
       total-width = \pgflinewidth   % <- optional
     }
  }

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{pNiceArray}{ccc:c}
\Block{3-3}{d(f_0)_{x_0}} 
& & & a_1    \\
& & & \Vdots \\
& & & a_1    \\ 
\hdashedline
0 & \Ldots &  0 & 1
\end{pNiceArray}
\]

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because of the PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Nice! How do you make the 3 dots spaced apart like the picture?

Comment: Instead of `\Ldots` (which is a command of `nicematrix`), you can use the classical `\ldots` and you will have three dots...

Comment: what about ```\vdots```? they are not spaced like the ones in the textbook

Comment: `\Ldots`, `\Vdots` and `\Ddots` are command of `nicematrix` which draws continuous dotted line accross multiple cells of the matrix. I've used them as illustration. You can use the classical `\ldots`, `\vdots` and `\ddots` if you want...